# php simple server/client (UDP, datagram) cant see each others

Tags: php, sockets, client

server:

```
 $address = '127.0.0.1';
 $port = 46123;
 if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
     echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n"; die;
 }
 echo 'socket_create OK '.$address.':'.$port."\n";
 if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
     echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n"; die;
 }
 if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
     echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n"; die;
 }

 do {
     if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
         echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
         break;
     }
```

client:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
$in = ';lsdkf';
var_dump (socket_sendto($socket, $in,strlen($in), 0,'127.0.0.1',46123));
```

client says OK but server doesnt get the message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your client is using UDP vs the server using TCP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server is not actually a UDP server. Replace

```
if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
```

with

```
if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP)) === false) {
```

and use [`socket_recvfrom`](http://php.net/socket_recvfrom) instead of `socket_accept` (which makes no sense for a UDP server).